# on click toggle ul - on click elsewhere hide ul

Tags: jquery

hey all - my second day of attempting jquery on a task at work, and am a bit stuck.

i've got an unordered list of links.. inside an unordered list of links

on clicking an `<li class="headlink">`, I would like the `<li class="headlink">` 's child `<ul>` to become visible.

on clicking away (anywhere on the document), I would like the child `<ul>` to dissapear.

By default the child `<ul>` is set to hidden in the stylesheet.

html

```
<ul id="cssdropdown">
    <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
    <li class="headlink">
        <a href="#">B</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
</ul>
```

jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#cssdropdown li.headlink').click(
            function() { $('ul', this).toggle("slow"); });
    });


    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('body').click(function() { 
            $('li ul:visible').hide("slow") } ) } );

</script>
```

Problem - when I click on a `<li class="headlink">`, I get the yoyo effect, where the child UL is displayed - and then hides itself.

any advise much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You should prevent the event to propagate back to the body:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cssdropdown li.headlink').click(function(event) {
      $('ul', this).toggle("slow");
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

And to hide current open items:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cssdropdown li.headlink').click(function(event) {
      $(this).siblings(".headlink").hide("slow");
      $('ul', this).toggle("slow");
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks - it works - well almost.. details under altCognitos answer

Comment: See my updated answer to achieve the effect you're looking for.

Comment: Thats it! Many thanks..

slight modification:

$(this).siblings(".headlink").children('ul').hide("slow");

tested firefox, ie, opera

Answer (score 1):

This will fix the issue for the "yo-yo" effect: (cancel propagation)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cssdropdown li.headlink').click(
        function(event) { 
          $('ul', this).toggle("slow"); 
          event.stopPropagation()
      });
});
```

Comment: manythanks..

ok, it works.. but I've got multiple headlinks with child ULs.

now clicking on one shows the child UL. clicking on another - shows its subsequent UL - but it doesn't hide the UL that was opened previously..

however, clicking away hides all child ULs..

close but no cigar.. :)

Comment: I think what you're in need of here is a better selector. Use an ID combined with a parent selector and I think you'll get more accuracy in your targeting.